# how can i define ">" method on my own record type in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a record like that:

```
(defrecord MyRec [name val])
```

I would like to compare instances based on the val field:

```
(def foo (->MyRec :foo 1))
(def bar (->MyRec :bar 2))
(> foo bar)
=> false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should exclude `clojure.core/>` from ns declaration like this:

```
(ns foo
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [>]))
```

And then try this:

```
(defprotocol FooComparable
  (> [a b]))

(defrecord MyRec [name val]
  FooComparable
  (> [a b] (clojure.core/> (:val a) (:val b))))

(def a (MyRec. :foo 1))
(def b (MyRec. :bar 2))

(> a b) ; false
(> b a) ; true
```

Comment: Why not to use `java.util.comparator` generic interface?

Comment: If I understand you right you ask why not to use `java.util.Comparator` instead of `FooComparable`? The reason is just about I suppose that author wants function to be called exactly as `>`